# Экспорт файлов на стороне сервера с возможностью выбора места куда сохранять

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, backend

Всем привет. Я юзаю Express, Node, React.

У меня на клиенте есть кнопка Export. Я ее нажимаю и отправляю на сервер объект. Затем из этого объекта делаю xml и архивирую их. вот код

```
const JSZip = require("jszip");    
app.post('/export', function (req, res) {
      var zip = new JSZip();
      zip.file("file1.xml", convert.json2xml(req.body.obj1, { compact: true, ignoreComment: true, spaces: 4 }));
      zip.file("file2.xml", convert.json2xml(req.body.obj2, { compact: true, ignoreComment: true, spaces: 4 }));
      zip.generateNodeStream({ 
        type: 'nodebuffer', 
        streamFiles: true, 
        compression: "DEFLATE",
        compressionOptions: {
            level: 9
        } 
      })
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('xdd.zip')) // на этой стадии на сервере создается валидный архив. все работает хорошо. но мне надо сохранить его не на сервере, а в выбранном мной в браузере месте.
      .on('finish', function (result) {  // result == undefined
          res.download(path.join(__dirname, 'xd.sflow'))
          // res.end(file);
      });  
    });
```

на стороне клиента

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
return axios.post(`${apiUrl}` + 'export', data)
    .then(response => {
        var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
        saveAs(blob, "test.zip");
        dispatch(exportFlowSuccess(response.data))
})
```

да. после того как на сервере файлы заархивируется, и клиент получит ответ. браузер спрашивает куда сохранить файл. я выбираю место. сохраняю. файл сохраняется в нужное мне место. Но!

но, файл уже не валидный. он не такой же как сохраненный ранее на сервере.

понятно что я на клиент что-то не то передаю, но что надо передавать, я так и не понимаю

Comment: Вы сохраняете ZIP в файл `xdd.zip`, а отправляете клиенту другой - `xd.sflow`. Это так и задумано? Ну и вообще, можно же сразу cделать `.pipe(res)`, только вместо `res.download()` использовать `res.attachment()` для предварительной установки нужного заголовка.

Comment: @Yaant так не задумано, просто опечатка. 
в `res.attachment()` необходимо указать путь. а какой он будет, если я напишу 
`zip.generateNodeStream({ 
    type: 'nodebuffer', 
    streamFiles: true, 
    compression: "DEFLATE",
    compressionOptions: {
        level: 9
    } 
  })
  .pipe(res.attachment(????))`

Comment: Не надо указывать путь. У Вас есть поток. `res` - это тоже поток, причем writeable. соответственно, можно писать прямо в него: `.pipe(res)`. И где-то раньше, вызвать `res.attachment()` без параметров. Параметр для `res.attachment()` указывает имя файла, с которым он будет сохраняться на клиенте, но Вы же все равно присваиваете это имя самостоятельно. Единственно, меня смущает, почему у Вас в клиентской части написано `{type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"}`? Откуда там должен взяться текст, если Вы передаете бинарный файл?